# How to access the micro SD card reader on raspberry PI

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, sd-card, card-reader

I am trying to access micro SD card reader plugged in with a 64GB card but unable to access via Raspian.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

There is another USB drive attached to the Raspberry Pi which I am able to access on `/dev/sda1`,

Plugging in and out I know that this device is attached at Port 3 and dev 6.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ lsblk -t
NAME        ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED    RQ-SIZE  RA WSAME
sda                 0    512      0     512     512    1 deadline     128 128    0B
`-sda1              0    512      0     512     512    1 deadline     128 128    0B
mmcblk0             0    512      0     512     512    0 deadline     128 128    0B
|-mmcblk0p1         0    512      0     512     512    0 deadline     128 128    0B
`-mmcblk0p2         0    512      0     512     512    0 deadline     128 128    0B
```

Not sure if the driver needs to be installed for this device before accessing it or I am missing something here?

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/ | grep usb`

Comment: @EugenRieck
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/ | grep usb

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 30 04:30 platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdb

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 30 01:17 platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sda

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 30 01:17 platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1`

Answer (score 2):

[Raspberry Pi](http://doc.xdevs.com/doc/RPi/pi3-block-diagram-rev4.png) has a dedicated SD controller which has nothing to do with USB. Probably that's why you can't get to it over the USB stack.

[image]